# mongo db connection issue "Cannot call method 'update' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, iot

i have set up a mongoldb connection as in this code

```
client.connect(mongodbURL,function (err,db){
   if(err) throw err;
   collection=db.collection("accel1");
 });
```

later in the code, i update documents to a collection inside a function that is repeated in intervals

```
setInterval(create_doc,db_doc_interval);

 function create_doc(){
 console.log("writing to db");

 collection.update( <...updates> );
 }
```

the problem is it gives an error

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'update' of undefined
```

which makes me think that somehow collection is not being defined correctly or it is not being passed into the function correctly. any help is greatly appreciated. thanks

BTW code works fine if i put the establishing connection part inside the second function were collection is called. but this causes a new connection to be established every time and is very resource intensive

Comment: where did you defined collection?

Comment: show us update statement as this makes an error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused by the `collection` variable is NOT be assigned in the callback function of `client.connect`, before it is invoked in the `create_doc` function through accessing `.update` function. Move `setInterval` function into the callback of `client.connect(` as below.

```
client.connect(mongodbURL,function (err,db){
     if(err) throw err;
     collection=db.collection("accel1");
     setInterval(create_doc,db_doc_interval);
 });
```